# JavaScript: Remove object whose property === value

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON string which I am storing in a Redis key. I add an object to this key whenever a user is added to another users list. How can I remove that object whose name property matches the value to be removed.

```
[{"name":"srtyt1","wins":0,"losses":0,"levels":0,"color":1672960,"avatar":[]},
 {"name":"srtyt2","wins":0,"losses":0,"levels":0,"color":1672960,"avatar":[]}, 
 {"name":"srtyt3","wins":0,"losses":0,"levels":0,"color":1672960,"avatar":[]} ]
```

The above string is the result from Redis which I am parsing into `allFriends`. I also have a variable `exFriend` which will hold the value of one of the name properties.

Is there a way to remove the object whose name property equals `"srtyt1"`? Or will I need to restructure my data? I saw this loop in the Mozilla docs for maps, but I guess it does not work with objects?

```
    let allFriends = JSON.parse(result);

    //iterate through all friends until I find the one to remove and then remove that index from the array
    for (let [index, friend] of allFriends) {
      if (friend.name === exFriend) {
        //remove the friend and leave
        allFriends.splice(index, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
```

Comment: `data = data.filter(o => o.name !== 'srtyt1')`.

Comment: or it you need to do it in place: `allFriends.splice(allFriends.findIndex(o => o.name = "srtyt1"), 1)`

Comment: Splicing exFriends sounds sinister!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can "filter" items from the array that need your `friend.name === exFriend` criteria by doing the following:

```js
const exFriend = 'srtyt1';
const inputArray = 
[{"name":"srtyt1","wins":0,"losses":0,"levels":0,"color":1672960,"avatar":[]},
 {"name":"srtyt2","wins":0,"losses":0,"levels":0,"color":1672960,"avatar":[]}, 
 {"name":"srtyt3","wins":0,"losses":0,"levels":0,"color":1672960,"avatar":[]} ];
 
 
 const outputArray = inputArray.filter(item => {
  
  return item.name !== exFriend;
 });
 
 console.log(outputArray);
```

Comment: That will definitely work and it leaves room for me to easily save the old array as former friends or something of that nature. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! :)